# Using TensorFlow functions, how do I set value smaller than 0.05 be zero?

Tags: tensorflow

I need a self-defined activation that set tensor value smaller than 0.05 to be zero. How do I do this with TensorFlow operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options :

**First**
You can just use `tf.maximum(tensor-0.05 , 0)`

**Second :** 
You can use a relu function with some biais : [image].

For example use `tf.nn.relu(x-0.05)`

Answer (score 2):

Do you want your activation to act as a soft-threshold or a hard-threshold? 
Let me explain:

- If what you want is a soft-threshold, then ReLU can do the trick:

  ```
  tf.nn.relu(x-0.05)
  ```

  Then for the domain `x>0.05` your activation won't be the identity but will return `x-0.05`
- If you want an hard-threshold then maybe you can use tf.sign(x-0.05) to create your activation. There might be cleaner ways to do this but the following code does that:

  ```
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])
  hard_threshold = 0.5*(1+tf.sign(x-0.05))*x
  xx = np.array([[1.], [0.02], [-1.], [2]]) #test data
  with tf.Session() as session:
      print(session.run(hard_threshold, feed_dict={x: xx}))
  ```